# Running an exe from Windows Service in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2, watin, windows

I am trying to automate(not fully, but some part of) my website using WatiN library in c#. I followed different strategies and applications but everyone has its own limitations. And so far I haven't found a complete solution yet. I have almost gone through all threads related to these approaches on stackoverflow, msdn and codeproject.

My application needs to be running on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IE10(if it matters for WatiN).

I developed following applications.

**1-Windows Service :** Developed a windows service and installed it on development machine(win7) and it worked fine. It successfully communicated with WatiN IE. No problem but didn't work on server 2008 R2.
To solve this problem, moved everything in a windows application(exe) and tried to run it from windows service. And that also didn't help.

**2-System Tray Application:** Developed a UI less System Tray application and installed on win7 and windows server 2008 r2 using remote desktop. It perfectly worked. But when logged out from server. Tray application exits itself. Because there is no session available to run it.

**3- Webservice:** Developed a web service to run the exe(tray application). And then windows service consumed this webservice. But that didn't work either.

So what I am looking for a solution to to execute WatiN IE and browse my website. So that after every 15 minutes I get updates from my website. My website is not on the same windows server 2008r2.

Looking for any of these solutions
1-windows application independent of windows session so that it always keep running.
2-windows service 
3-webservice so that a windows service can consume.

A nice work around would highly be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you using watin for? Why do you need to automate a browser? Couldn't you just make requests and parse what comes back?

Comment: I am using this library to log into my website using my credentials.

Comment: Did you configure the service to run with your credentials?

Comment: As I said in my question that windows service and webservice works on win7, I tested there. So these configuration or how to use watin related stuff are out of question. I put my question to get some work around for windows server so that my working application can be deployed there.

Comment: ... To log in and do what exactly? Just logging in seems kind of pointless to me...

Comment: The only difference between Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 that seems relevant is IE Enhanced Security Configuration, so you could try turning that off.  If that doesn't work, I would strongly recommend testing it on a vanilla (i.e., clean install) Windows 7 machine, to eliminate other potential variables.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes that was the first thing on windows server which I did.

Comment: Come to think of it, ESC might not turn off for services, or it might depend on what credentials they use.  I'm not quite sure how you could test that theory.  There aren't really all that many other differences between 7 and 2008R2.  Unless WatiN is trying to listen on a TCP/IP port below 1024 without admin privilege?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the service?  It's hard to advise without a better idea of what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No ESC is still off. Not sure about the port which WatiN uses.

Yes windows service just gives nothing when you instantiates IE(url) or objIE.GoTo(url). In both cases it just gives nothing.

The thing which puzzles me is that this windows service perfectly works on Win7 but does nothing on server.